# Return model objects with JSON field

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

Lets say I want to get all the objects from a Model where one of it's field is JSON stored as string

So the object will look something like this after serializated from the model:

`[{
    "model": "Book",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields" :{
        "title": 'Book 1',
        "content": "{
            "content1": "abc",
            "content2": "def"
        }"
    },
    "model": "Book",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields" :{
        "title": 'Book 2',
        "content": "{
            "content1": "123",
            "content2": "456"
        }"
    },
}]`

`objList =  serializers.serialize('json', Books.objects.all()
context = {
    'objList': objList
}
return  render(request, template, context)`

Are there any way to make sure the content field to be returned as JSON?

Tried use `{{objList|safe}}` but that doesn't makes the content field to be JSON. The content field returned as string when I use it in the javascript.

Comment: Do you store `content` as string in db ?

Comment: You can either add a specific condition in `serializer` or you can parse it to json on frontend before using it.

Comment: @Panther Yes, its stored as CharField in db. I tried to `JSON.parse` in frontend but have error of invalid token ' in JSON